# Fetch the latest data using date in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to fetch the latest data from MongoDB in nodejs. let me explain with an example every 2hours I am uploading the data to a collection. when I do a get method I need the latest data how do I do that.

Please help me with this issue.

```
Here is the Schema
var abc = new mongoose.Schema({
    ItemName : String,
    date:   Date
         ......
});
This is how I am storing 

finalData.push({
                ItemName: xyz,
                date: new Date()})

abc.insertMany(finalData)
```

Comment: did you try to use setInterval that sends the request every 2 hours ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this:

```
your_model_name.find({}).sort('-date').exec(function(err, docs) { ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can sort your collection and get the desired document by limiting the document size to one.

```
abc.find({}).sort([['date', -1]]).limit(1).exec(function(err, doc) { });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. abc.find({}).sort('date').limit(1).then(data=>console.log(data))
2. criteria can be asc, desc, ascending, descending, 1, or -1 
   abc.find({}).sort({ field : criteria}).limit(1).exec(function(err, data){ });

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the last ten records from MongoDB express js

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    number: String,
    avatar: String,
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }

);

const userFind = await UserData.findOne({
  createdAt: { $gte: new Date(Date.now() - 600000) },
});
```